# connect input type to model and assign them a value in asp net

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add values to a cross table, where the ID of a garage and a value based on a list of choices gets inserted to the database. The list looks like following in the view:

```
 <div class='form-group' style="margin-left: 60%;">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="ab">Claim</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="Claim" id="Claim" placeholder="Claim" required="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='form-group' style="margin-left: 60%;">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="ab">Scheduled Service</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="Scheduled" id="Scheduled" placeholder="Scheduled" required="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='form-group' style="margin-left: 60%;">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="ab">Tires</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="Tires" id="Tires" placeholder="Tires" required="" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

So 3 checkboxes is shown in the view. Here the  user is supposed to choice one or more options when they edit a garage. The cross table looks like following:

```
   [ID]
  ,[GarageID]
  ,[RequestProperty]
  ,[CreatedDate]
  ,[CreatedBy]
  ,[UpdatedDate]
  ,[UpdatedBy]
```

I would like to do something similar to this in SQL stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO GarageCrossRequestType
(GarageID, RequestProperty)
VALUES (@GarageID, @RequestType)
```

Which could look something similar to:

```
var cmd1 = new SqlCommand("spGarageGetRequestTypes", Connection);
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GarageId", model.GarageId);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestType", model.requestId);

                    int result = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (result == 1)
                    valid = true;
```

In the method. (To insert the `garageID` and the `RequestTypeID`.)

The Request-types can be as following:

```
        public int Claim { get; set; } = 1;
        public int ScheduledService { get; set; } = 2;
        public int Tires { get; set; } = 3;
```

So for example, if a user choose Claim, I would like to update the table with the `GarageID` and `Claim` -> which `ID` would be 1.  I'm sort of new to working with views, so I'm not sure how I would connect the input types to the model. So the problems are as following:

1. Connect the input types to the model, giving them their correct value (ex. Claim -> 1, Scheduled -> 2 etcetera) and,
2. My database table only accept `garageId` and `requestType`, and therefore when sending for example `garageId: 4`, I would need the input type Claim or whatever checkbox is choosen to only send their value (1, 2 or 3) to the database.

Anyone got a solution for this? Also I hope this makes sense, let me know otherwise and i'll try to formulate it differently.

**UPDATE:**
So I should have explained better from the beginning. But here's the rest of the code. So basically, there's a function where a user can *Edit a garage*  where I would like to make it possible for them to also choose either claim/service or tires. So I would like to *expand this method*, and when a user selects a garage this is when they also can choose claim etcetera (It's also from this method the `garageId` comes from).

In the view (for edit garage):

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Garage</label>
                    <input type="text" class="col-lg-10 form-control" name="GarageName" id="GarageName" placeholder="Name" required="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Contact person</label>
                    <input type="text" class="col-lg-10 form-control" name="ContactPerson" id="ContactPerson" placeholder="ContactPerson" required="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="col-lg-10 form-control" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" required="" onblur="validateEmail(this.value);" /><p id="InvalidMeg" style="font-size: 25px; color: red">Invalid e-mail address</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary custom" type="submit" id="saveNewGarageBtn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>&nbsp;Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary custom" type="submit" id="EditGarageBtn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>&nbsp;Save edit</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function editGarage(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
            var garageId = dataItem.GarageId;
            countryId = dataItem.CountryId;
            name = dataItem.Name;
            var contactperson = dataItem.ContactPerson;
            var email = dataItem.Email;
            if (garageId != 0) {
                $("#EditGarageBtn").show();
                $("#saveNewGarageBtn").hide();
                $("#GarageName").val(name);
                $("#Country").val(countryId);
                $("#ContactPerson").val(contactperson);
                $("#Email").val(email);
                $("#garageId").val(garageId);
            }
        }

Edit-garage button:
  $("#EditGarageBtn").click(function () {
            var customerNumber = customerNumberOfEditingGarage;

            name = $("#GarageName").val();
            countryId = $("#Country").val();
            var garageId = $("#garageId").val();
            var contactperson = $("#ContactPerson").val();
            var email = $("#Email").val();

            $("#EditGarageBtn").hide();

            if (countryId == "Norway")
                countryId = 2;
            if (countryId == "Finland")
                countryId = 4;
            
            if (name.length > 0 && email.length > 0 && phone.length > 0 && contactperson.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("EditGarage", "Garage")',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    name: name, countryId: countryId, garageId: garageId,
                    contactperson: contactperson,
                    phone: phone, email: email
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "Failure") {
                        toastr["error"]("Error editing Garage");
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr["success"]("Garage successfully updated");
                        customerNumberOfEditingGarage = null;
                        refreshGrid();
                    }
                },
                error: function () {

                }
            });
            } else {
                toastr["error"]("Error editing Garage");
            }
        });
```

Method:

```
public bool EditGarage(GarageModel model)
        {
            var valid = false;

            var cmd = new SqlCommand("spGarageEditGarage", Connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GarageId", model.GarageId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryId", model.CountryId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactPerson", model.ContactPerson);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", model.Email);
            try
            {

                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (result == 1)
                    valid = true;
            }

            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);

            }
            finally
            {
                Connection.Close();
            }
            return valid;
        }
```

Hopefully, this became a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what your model is and where `model.GarageId` comes from. If you complete the part I did not understand, you can use the following code for `model.requestId`.

**note**: Use a `radiobutton` instead of a `checkbox`.

change view to :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
 <div class='form-group' style="margin-left: 60%;">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="radio" id="Claim" name="requestType" value="Claim">
    <label for="Claim">Claim</label>
    < </div>
  </div>
  <div class='form-group' style="margin-left: 60%;">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="radio" id="ScheduledService" name="requestType" value="ScheduledService">
      <label for="ScheduledService">ScheduledService</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='form-group' style="margin-left: 60%;">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="radio" id="Tires" name="requestType" value="Tires">
      <label for="Tires">Tires</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='form-group' style="margin-left: 60%;">
    <div class="row">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
}
```

add enum

```
 public enum RequestType
 {
    Claim = 1,
    ScheduledService = 2,
    Tires = 3
 }
```

in your action

```
public ActionResult YourAction(RequestType requestType)
{
    //......................................
    model.GarageId = //your value
    switch (requestType)
    {
        case RequestType.Claim:
          model.requestId = (int)RequestType.Claim;
          break;
        case RequestType.ScheduledService:
          model.requestId = (int)RequestType.ScheduledService;
          break;
       case RequestType.Tires:
          model.requestId = (int)RequestType.Tires;
          break;
    }

    //get insert........................
}
```

Comment: i've posted an update if you want more information about code! But thank you I will try this